# Remove element and children from XML with elementtree Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, element, elementtree

Tried a few different libraries now and think im close but cant figure out this problem.

I have an XML file with some nested tables which I want to remove. These are several levels down the XML hierarchy.

So far I have tried this...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

tree = ET.parse('/Users/me/file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for sect1 in root.findall('section1'):
    for sect2 in sect1.iter() :
        if sect2.tag == 'table':
            sect1.remove(sect2)
```

However I get the error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I can successfully remove sections of the document from the top level of the hierarchy using the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

tree = ET.parse('/Users/me/file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for sect1 in root.findall('section1'):
    root.remove(sect1)
```

Im just missing how to remove elements which are further down from the top level.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
for sect1 in root.findall('.//section1'):
root.remove(sect1)
```

the `.//` selects from all child section1 elements from the first element. you can be more specific selecting elements with `'./section1/section2'`  also selecting elements with particular attributes is possible with`./section1[@Name="SomeValueForNameAttribute"]'`  if you'd like to know more this is called xpath and the boiled down version that element tree offers is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

I use minidom to parse xml files and strings and it's so easy with minidom to do anything you want, and this is an example which you requested but using `xml.dom.minidom` library:-

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

doc = parse('/Users/me/file.xml')
root = doc.documentElement

for parent in root.childNodes:
    for child in parent.childNodes:
        if(child.tagName == 'table'):
            parent.removeChild(child)
```